# undefined returned from function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple recursive function that is returning undefined instead of the desired string.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

```
var someString = 'item1|item2|item3|item4';
        console.log( testData(someString, '|', 2) );

        function testData( data, token, count ) {   
            console.log(data);
            if( count == 0 ) { 
                return data; 
            } else {
                testData( data.substring( data.indexOf( token ) + 1 ), token, count - 1 );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `return` statement in your `else` clause:

```
else {
    return testData( data.substring( data.indexOf( token ) + 1 ), token, count - 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only ever `return` if `count` is `0`.

You probably want to stick a `return` in before `testData()`.