# JavaScript + recursive function returning undefined

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a simple html structure that I need to traverse.  For some reason my recursive function returns 'undefined' on any nested nodes, but not for parent nodes.  Unfortunately this needs to be native js, no jQuery for this one.  Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="head"> 
    <span id="left"><</span> 
    <span id="right">></span> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
var h = hasId(container, 'head');
var l = hasId(container, 'left');
var r = hasId(container, 'right');

console.log(h + " : " + r + " : " + l);
//[object HTMLDivElement] : undefined : undefined

function hasId(ele, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = ele.childNodes[i];
        if(child.id == id) return child;
        else hasId(child, id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421207/undefined-returned-from-function)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are simply the call to `return` on the recursive call. Also, you should test whether its result is defined. If yes, you can return it, or continue looping if not.

```
var h = hasId(container, 'head');
var l = hasId(container, 'left');
var r = hasId(container, 'right');

console.log(h + " : " + r + " : " + l);
//[object HTMLDivElement] : undefined : undefined

function hasId(ele, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = ele.childNodes[i];
        if(child.id == id) return child;
        else {
          var next = hasId(child, id);
          if(next) return next;
        };
    }
}​
```

Comment: your code is right, but you've fixed a much more subtle bug without explaining why.  It's not _just_ a missing `return`, as I had originally answered, but the fact that this return _only_ happens if the result of the recursion was itself defined.

Comment: You're welcome =) On recursive call, the loop should continue if the result is undefined. So returning it directly doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks!!! Worked great...made sense once I read through this example, much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The `else` clause should `return` the value of `hasId(child, id)`, but only if that value is itself defined, otherwise it has to continue through the loop.

Without a `return` the function will recurse, but not give an answer.

Comment: Just putting `else return hasId(...)` does not work.  Pierre's answer, checking that the answer is defined, is correct.

Comment: @PaulPhillips I spotted that just now too, but even Pierre's answer is incomplete - it never unwinds the recursion properly.

Comment: @PaulPhillips ah, no, Pierre's answer does appear to fix that.

Comment: Ha, I didn't actually read it.  On the test input @worked gave, it succeeds: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaxmH/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this :

```
var h = hasId(container, 'head');
var l = hasId(container, 'left');
var r = hasId(container, 'right');

console.log(h + " : " + r + " : " + l);

function hasId(ele, id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < ele.childNodes.length; i++) {
        var child = ele.childNodes[i];
        if(child.id == id || (child = hasId(child, id))){
           return child;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. If the recurring call does not return any element, your function still returns, when it needs to continue iterating through elements.