# Variable becomes undefined in recursive javascript function?

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I've got a simple script that I've written to find greatest common divisors (GCDs) and least common multiples (LCMs) using a recursive method- Euclid's algorithm.

Unfortunately if it needs to do this in more than one step the relevant variable to be returned from the function becomes undefined. I've tried following it in a debugger with breakpoints, which seems to follow the recursion adequately and go back to the original function appropriately, but it then mysteriously vanishes at the end of the function even though it's meant to be returned?

Not sure why this is happening or what I can do to fix it. My code is below:

```
function GCD(a, b) {
    if (a % b == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        GCD(b, (a % b));
    }
}

function LCM (a, b) {
    return (a*b)/GCD(a, b);
}

function makeDM (a, b) {
    return (GCD(a, b) + " " + LCM(a, b));
}
```

So if you use a & b such as 60, 20 it will give the correct answers of 20 and 60. However if you use numbers such as 20, 60 or 126, 35 it fails miserably.

Comment: I pasted you code to try in http://ideone.com/, and it gave me the warning on line 2: Use '===' to compare with 0.

Comment: One of the paths in `GCD` doesn't have a `return` in it. That's fishy.

Comment: Is this what you're trying to do -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wEv8Y/) ??

Comment: you are missing a `return` in the last statement of GCD

Comment: Thanks guys! Fixed now :). I knew I was missing something fundamental about this. Time to do more reading I guess :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421207/undefined-returned-from-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not returning the value from the recursive part of the function, so the value returned from the function will be `undefined`. Add a `return`:

```
function GCD(a, b) {
    if (a % b == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    else {
        return GCD(b, (a % b));
    }
}
```

You can also write this with a single `return`:

```
function GCD(a, b) {
    return a % b == 0 ? b : GCD(b, (a % b));
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, I knew I had to have been missing something utterly fundamental hehe :)