# Return value of recursive function is 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

Whenever I execute this snippet the console.log before return returns the array with 20 times the value 23.
However console.log(Check(users, 0, 20)); returns only 'undefined'.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var users = [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23];
console.log(Check(users, 0, 20));

function Check(ids, counter, limit){
    ids.push(23);

    // Recursion
    if (counter+1 < limit){
        Check(ids, counter+1, limit);
    }
    else {
        console.log(ids);
        return ids;
    }
}
```

Comment: No `return` statement in the `if` block means `undefined`. It might be easier to maintain if you put one `return` statement at the end of the function and set the value to return based on the `if` statement

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421207/undefined-returned-from-function)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You forgot to return a result from the point, where you entering recusrion.

```
var users = [23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23];
console.log(Check(users, 0, 20));

function Check(ids, counter, limit){
    ids.push(23);

    // Recursion
    if (counter+1 < limit){
        return Check(ids, counter+1, limit); // return here!
    }
    else {
        console.log(ids);
        return ids;
    }
}
```

But return value seems useless, cause' your function altering initial array as well.

Comment: I simplified the function as much as possible in order to not distract from the real problem. Thanks a lot.