# Getting 'undefined' when trying to return a value from a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion

So I have this recursive function which takes in two parameters, `factor` and `width`. The `factor` will decrement in every recursive instance by `0.05`. And in every instance it will be multiplied with `width` to get a value.

If this value is greater than `900` then the recursive function will continue. If it is less than `900` then it will stop and return the factor value.

Right now I'm getting `undefined` but if I log all the factors then I can see that there are numbers before undefined but it stops with undefined.

How can I get the factor value which is just before `undefined`?

Here's the snippet:

```js
function findFactor(factor, width) {

  let nextFactor = factor - 0.05;
  let value = width * nextFactor;

  console.log(nextFactor);

  if (value < 900) {
    return nextFactor;
  } else {
    findFactor(nextFactor, width);
  }

}

console.log(findFactor(1, 2400));
```

Comment: Is this for [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/90527)?

Comment: Ummm yeahhhh :'(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [undefined returned from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421207/undefined-returned-from-function)

Comment: Yes and the answer below is also great. Why dont we find these answers while searching? I searched for a while and havent found anything.

Comment: Depends on your search strategy. I searched for "[javascript] return recursive undefined" and found quite a few answers. In my case, it was complicated by having to sort by age rather than relevance (as I was looking for the oldest question to link as an original).

Comment: ... There were irrelevant questions as well, but a large part of that is the number of low-quality and repeated questions on SO these days.

Comment: Thanks mate. I didn't know SO searches can be that specific.

Comment: forgot to `return findFactor `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are properly returning the result in case `if (value < 900) {`. However, you forgot to return the result of the subsequent recursive call. Adding `return` should solve your problem:

```js
else {
  return findFactor(nextFactor, width);
}
```

Comment: [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) shouldn't merely be code-drops, but should include explanations.

Comment: Thank you, will add a small explanation